# Remove the number after space

Tags: r

I have the following data set:

```
id <- c(1,2,3,4)
x1 <- c("1234564 0", "2345673 1", "6487591 0", "2345610 0")
mdata <- data.frame(id,x1)
```

For column x1, I need to remove either the 0 or 1 after the space. So the final data is:

```
id  x1
1   1234564
2   2345673
3   6487591
4   2345610
```

Comment: 'gsub("([0-9])\\s[0-9]","\\1",x)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mdata$x1 <- sub(" .*", "", mdata$x1)
  id      x1
1  1 1234564
2  2 2345673
3  3 6487591
4  4 2345610
```

The pattern matches and eliminates a space followed by any other characters.